# Can't connect cloudflare warp vpn in linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, cloudflare-apps

I installed and set up cloudflare warp in linux as [cloudflare document](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-docs/blob/production/products/warp-client/src/content/setting-up/linux.md).

After "start warp-svc.service" and do `warp-cli connect` successfully,

I check warp status in https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace/:

> warp=off

And I can't access to the blocked websites.

How to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I think you disabled IPv6 before, I got the same problem with warp-cli after I disabled IPv6. You can re-enble it by:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.<your device>.disable_ipv6=0
```

Comment: That was also my problem! thanks. I think warp-cli should be able to pinpoint this and show a message

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the issues for me.  Post the error messages shown in syslog when IPv6 is disabled to make searching this issue easier.

`Aug  8 09:33:35 smsudt systemd-udevd[13876]: CloudflareWARP: Failed to get link config: No such device
Aug  8 09:33:35 smsudt libvirtd[1216]: Failed to open file '/sys/class/net/CloudflareWARP/operstate': No such file or directory
Aug  8 09:33:35 smsudt libvirtd[1216]: unable to read: /sys/class/net/CloudflareWARP/operstate: No such file or directory`

Comment: safety tricks: Before running those comments first check actually it is disabled or not. Go to `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all`, `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/default` and `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/<your device>`  folder. In all folders open file `disable_ipv6` and check the value weather it 0 or something other. This is the value you going to change

Answer (score 3):

Let check your current status by the command:

```
warp-cli status
```

I'm guessing your warp status is: **Registration missing** :D

For me, I have to run register one more time:

```
warp-cli register
```

Now, you can connect successfully with the command:

```
warp-cli connect
```

Enjoy the connection!